# setTimeOut/setInterval runs just once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, settimeout

I use function App.loadTo to load some data in any place. I need a delay before displaying any content (used form-styler plugin, redrawing form). I tried setTimeout and setInterval functions, but they run just once, i.e.

1) Called App.loadTo( params ) - delay works

2) Called App.loadTo( params ) with the same params - delay doesnt work

I tried the following with no success

```
            tmp = setInterval(function() {
                console.log('I show all invisible!', params.where);
                $(params.where).css({
                    'visibility': 'visible'
                });
                $('#preloader').remove();
                clearInterval(tmp);
            }, 110);
```

Where did I make a mistake?

```
App.loadTo = function loadTo(params) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/' + params.controller + '/' + params.action + '',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: params.sentData,
        success: function(server_answer, textStatus) {
            if (server_answer.result == 'success') {
                if (params.hasOwnProperty('parseHtml')) {
                    // Data parsing
                    var html = $(server_answer.html);
                    html = $(html).find(params.parseBlock);
                } else {
                    var html = $(server_answer.html);
                }

                // Inserting data
                $(params.where).empty().html(html).css({
                    'visibility': 'hidden'
                }).before('<div id="preloader" style="width: 100%; background: url(&quot;i/preloader.gif&quot;) no-repeat scroll 50% center transparent; min-height: 140px; height: 100%;"></div>');

                // Delay before display
                setTimeout(function() {
                    console.log('I show all invisible!', params.where);
                    $(params.where).css({
                        'visibility': 'visible'
                    });
                    $('#preloader').remove();
                }, 110);
            } else {
                alert_jq_ui(server_answer.error_txt);
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
            alert_jq_ui(xhr, errmsg, err);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: `setTimeout()` runs just once.

Comment: OP means: when function is called the second time, interval will not fire. Logical problem though.

Comment: No that keeps running until you `clearInterval(varThatYouAssign_setInterval);`. 110 milliseconds is nothing, there are 1000 milliseconds in a second.

Comment: @PHPglue  ... in a second !!

Comment: It's hard to understand your question. When do you want your timer to stop running? If you use `setInterval`, you'll want to wrap your `clearInterval` in a conditional check before clearing if you need a certain condition to be met. For setTimeout, you'll need to call another timeout. If you always want it running in the background, use setInterval but don't clearInterval it...

Comment: I need just one delay after ajax succes.
1) ajax->succes->delay
2) ajax->succes->delay
3) ajax->succes->delay
but delay works just in the first ajax...

Comment: This code is severely unclear. When you work with other people, or as in this case when you ask for other people for help, you should really work on using self-explanatory variables and names for your objects first.

Comment: I guess the names are understandable... I want to change code you to understand... but dont know how - it is clear

Comment: `var html = $(server_answer.html); html = $(html).find(params.parseBlock);`? What is that? `html.find()`.

Comment: Is it still `$(params.where).empty()`?

Comment: parsing html from the specified tags of html-code, returned from server

Comment: What does doesn't work mean? You don't see the preloader image? You see the preloader image but then the content doesn't change?

Comment: "Doen't work" means - setInterval/setTimeout does fire when App.loadTo called the second time, as a result preloader is not deleted and hidden html stays hidden

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the setTimeout with clearTimeout(); if you choose to go with that, else if you rather want to try the setinterval method, try clearing it outside of itself, i hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I created a little fiddle, stripped down your code ... http://jsfiddle.net/gnsnvjtz/

The big difference here is this:

```
var App = {

     loadTo: function () {
       ///loadTo code goes here ...
     }

}
```

instead of `App.loadTo = function loadTo(params) ...